# Limit number of maps for CS:GO dedicated server (Multi1v1 plugin)

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike, server-administration, hosting

It's my first time trying to setup a CS:GO competitive server. I rented a server from gameservers.com and uploaded the Multi1v1 plugin on it (https://github.com/splewis/csgo-multi-1v1).

The README for the plugin isn't super detailed, but I figured out how to get most of it working. I made a Workshop collection of `am_*` maps (http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=416015088) and set the command line settings to use it.

After a server restart everything seemed to work fine, but checking the server after a few hours I see that the map mysteriously changed to `cs_office` and can't figure out why.

I want to setup the stats system and web interface as well, but for now I just want to make sure I got everything else right. I also don't know what's the best source to RTFM for this.

Thanks.

Edit: I added the nominate and RTV plugins and I see that the available maps to choose from are actually from the active duty map pool rather than my Workshop collection. Is this because of the maps_list file?

Edit 2: I've looked around for other threads on the same problem (didn't find anything on stack-exchange sites. So far I've:

- removed maplist.txt, mapcycle.txt, subscribed_collections_ids.txt and subscribed_file_ids.txt
- disabled nextmap.smx which apparently can cause problems

I'm now in the process of actually removing the active duty maps from the server, since rockthevote.smx seems to be reading them straight from the source. I'm not actually sure how to test that the auto map change won't change to one of the active duty maps again though unless I idle for 30 minutes on the server, any ideas on how to better test this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for Serverfault.com

Comment: Wait - what is the server-administration tag for then? Also, serverfault can hardly be relevant since this is about a CS:GO dedicated server, and specifically the Multi1v1 mod.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I don't think serverfault would accept this, it falls outside of their professional remit.

Comment: this seems to be an issue with the addon itself, if nobody here can answer you could go to https://forums.alliedmods.net/ and see if people there know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question was bumped:

Make sure you have all your [workshop settings](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Workshop_For_Server_Operators) set up correctly:

- Put your API key in the command line using `-authkey` or putting it in `webapi_authkey.txt` in the csgo directory.
- Put `+host_workshop_collection 416015088` in your startup line.
- Put `+workshop_start_map 319603095` (or another map ID from the list) in your startup line.

However, even with all that said, there's one last thing that will cause a problem:

If you use CS:GO's built-in map voting and use SourceMod, you **must** disable SourceMod's `nextmap` plugin by moving `addons/sourcemod/plugins/nextmap.smx` to the `addons/sourcemod/plugins/disabled/` folder.

This is because SourceMod will override the server's next map if a plugin tells it to.  Which the `nextmap` plugin does on startup.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.alliedmods.net/Map_Management_Plugins_(SourceMod)#Mapchooser

Mapchooser reads from mapcycle.txt by default, which is where you should be adding maps.

You either use sourcemod plugins (mapchooser, nextmap, rtv, nominate + mapcycle.txt) to manage the maps, or disable ALL of them and use the builtin game workshop support to manage the maps (where the maps come from whats in the collection).